# Display menu depending url

Tags: vue.js

I have to display icon in the side bar but depending the path, not display the same.

Admin have admin icons
Client have client icon 
....

but how to display it in Vue.

this is the code I use to display the client icon

```
      <div class="menu-items">
        <ul>
          <li v-on:click="routeLink()"><img class="img-menu" src="./assets/images/gauge.svg" alt="logo"><p>DashBoard</p></li>
          <li v-on:click="routeLink()"><img class="img-menu" src="./assets/images/plant.svg" alt="logo"><p>Ma Serre</p></li>
          <li v-on:click="routeLink()"><img class="img-menu" src="./assets/images/sunny.svg" alt="logo"><p>Recettes</p></li>
          <li v-on:click="routeLink()"><img class="img-menu" src="./assets/images/user.svg" alt="logo"><p>Mon compte</p></li>
          <li v-on:click="routeLink()"><img class="img-menu" src="./assets/images/help.svg" alt="logo"><p>Aide</p></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
```

I think i need to use v-show but don't know which syntax to write this

v-show="url === client"  ???

Comment: v-if="whatever"

Comment: It's not really clear what you're trying to achieve... If I understand correctly, you're mixing two things, one is showing an icon only when a specific route is active, the other is changing the icon deepending on the user's admin state?

Comment: for example, I want display a certain template if the path is..../client or I want to display another if path is .../admin

Comment: in angular I'm using *ngIf="router.url.startsWith('/admin')">